# How can I make a JavaScript while-loop for storing values that are divisible by two values?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a while-loop in JS that adds all the values to a comma-separated string, in the
range 28 to 63, where the value is divisable by 5 or 7.

My problem lies with finding a way to check if the value is divisible with **both** 5 or 7.

But I can't for the life of me get any further, any advice would be appriciated. 
 
This is how far I've come.

```
var text = "";
i = 28;

while (i < 63) {
    i++
    if (i % 5 || i % 7 === 0) {
        if (i === 28) text = i;
        else {
            text = text + "," + i
        }
    }
}

console.log(text);
```

And this is the outcome I'm getting

```
",29,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,41,42,43,44,46,47,48,49,51,52,53,54,56,57,58,59,61,62,63" (string)
```

Comment: There's quite a few issues to fix first. You start at 28 but immediately increase `i`, so the `if (i==28)` is never true. You stop at 63 but you said 68 in the question. `if (i % 5 || i % 7 === 0)` should be `if (i % 5 === 0 || i % 7 === 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a tiny error in your first `if` condition. It should be:

```
if (i % 5 === 0 || i % 7 === 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value to be divisible by both `5` and `7`, You need to change the conditional to: `if (i % 5 === 0 && i % 7 === 0)` if the value should be divisible by either `5` or `7` then `if (i % 5 === 0 || i % 7 === 0)`

Answer (score 0):

This will satisfy

```
var text = "";
i = 28;
while (i < 63) {
  i++
  if (i % 5 ===0 || i % 7 === 0) {
    if (i === 28) text = i;
    else {
      text = text.length ? `${text},${i}`:`${text}${i}`;
    }
  }
}
console.log(text);
```

The desired output will be as `"30,35,40,42,45,49,50,55,56,60,63"`

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
  var text = "";
  var iNum = 28;

  while (iNum < 68) {
      if ((iNum % 5 === 0) || (iNum % 7 === 0)) {
        text = iNum;
      }    else    {
        text = text + "," + iNum
      }
      iNum++
  }
  console.log(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that this may answer your question.

The first suggestion I would make would be to always create a complete condition. What I mean is that you have `i % 5 || i % 7 === 0` and it should be `i % 5 === 0 || i % 7 === 0`. See that I added `=== 0` to your first condition. Once you add a `||` or `&&` the two conditions are separated.

This example may answer your question:

```
i = 28;

while (i < 63) {
    i++
    if (i % 5 === 0 || i % 7 === 0 || i % 5 === 0 && i % 7 === 0) {
        if (i === 28) text = i;
        else {
            text = text + "," + i
        }
    }
}

console.log(text);
```

I added another `||` that used an AND/&& condition. That condition checks for the number being divisible by 5 and 7.